# Does the vagus nerve supply the human thoracic diaphragm?

Tags: human-anatomy, neuroanatomy

The vagus nerve (CN X) passes through the oesophageal hiatus of the diaphragm at the vertebral level T10.

But does the vagus nerve actually offer any nerve supply to the diaphragm?

Comment: No, it doesn't supply thoracoabdominal diaphragm.

Comment: Sensory and Motor Innervation of the Crural Diaphragm by the Vagus Nerves https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S001650850901511X?via%3Dihub